# Rotating a QGraphicsItem and finding the new position of it

Tags: qt, qt5

I am working on a tower defence game and trying to shoot a projectile from a turret. The sprite of the turret I have looks like this

[image]

Also, the bullet looks like this
[image]

What I want to do is make the turret shot the bullet to a certain point (for example `attackDestination = QPointF(1000, 500);`

for this, I have a class Bullet, with the slot `move`:

```
void Bullet::move()
{

    int stepSize = 20; // how fast the bullet moves
    double angle = rotation();

    double dy = stepSize * qSin(qDegreesToRadians(angle)); // The X that needs to be moved
    double dx = stepSize * qCos(qDegreesToRadians(angle)); // The Y that needs to be moved

    setPos(x() + dx, y() + dy);
}
```

which is triggered by a QTimer.

I also have a slot in the Tower class (which stands for the turret)

```
void Tower::attackTarget()
{
    Bullet *bullet = new Bullet();
    //getWidthMap() returns the width of the tower
    //getHeightMap() returns the height of the tower

    bullet->setPos(x() + getWidthMap() /2, y());

    QLineF line(QPointF(x() + getWidthMap() /2, y()), attackDestination);
    double angle =(-1) *  line.angle();

    bullet->setRotation(angle);

    this->setRotation(90 + angle);

    game->scene->addItem(bullet);

}
```

I have rotated the turret by +90 degrees because its initial position is vertical and it needs to form an angle (that of the line with oX) just like the bullet. The rotation happens clockwise.

**The problem is with the position of the bullet relative to the turret when attacking.**

Without the line `this->setRotation(90 + angle);` (first picture), with it (second picture)

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the bullets are starting from the initial position of the turret (when it was not rotated), because the pos() function keeps the initial X and Y. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Make a line that goes from the center of the turret to the tip of it and rotate it the same amount as you rotate your turret. Then get the second point of that line. This will give you the position of the turret's tip.

Comment: @thuga I will definitely try that, thanks !